# Border radius menu in expo react-native app: how delete white spaces in corners of the menu?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I use expo template for creating an application. I would like to make the bottom menu with border-radius, but I have white space instead of background the page. How to fix it? Example see on the image

My styles for createBottomTabNavigator:

```
    width: '100%',
    height: 94,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 51,
    borderTopRightRadius: 51,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderColor: '#68a0cf',
    overflow: 'hidden'
```

My styles for page(screen):

```
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  alignItems: 'flex-start'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the parent container for both the Bottom tab navigator and the page and style it with with = screenWidth and hight = screenHeight and make the background color blue of whatever you want.

By this way you will be able to get off with these white spaces.